# How to use an element in an array to print a textfile in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner with PHP code and I'm trying to figure out how to use a variable inside a file_get_contents.

I have an array of names that are associated with textfiles in a certain folder. I am trying to use the name in the array to print out the text file.

```
echo '<p>';  
echo nl2br(file_get_contents( "Files/"+$names[1]+".txt"));
echo '</p>';
```

Comment: note: if php-only, it's better to omit the closing php tag (`?>`)

Comment: the concatenation operator in PHP is `.`, not `+` - see [string operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In order to concatenate php variables with string, you need to use dot operator. In your case, the second line of code should be:

`echo nl2br(file_get_contents( "Files/" . $names[1] . ".txt"));`